# NULL behavior with Comoperator like ALL in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, null

```
SELECT * FROM   hr.NullValueCheck
```

```
ID      Name
1   abc
2   abc
3   bcd
4   cde
```

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql

Query 1 :

```
SELECT *
FROM   hr.NullValueCheck  
where id > All (SELECT NULL  FROM DUAL )
```

Nothing is coming.

But for below quesry. All records are coming while subquesry is returning is NULL same as like above query (SELECT NULL  FROM DUAL )

Query 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM   hr.NullValueCheck  
where id > All (SELECT id from  hr.NullValueCheck where id = 5)
```

Please explain me why Query 1 is returning No Records but Query 2 is returning all records.

As per my knowledge Query 1 should also return all records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is different from an empty set.

The first example is saying:  "select all rows where the id is greater than all values of `NULL`".  Or more simply, "where id is greater than 'NULL'`.

In SQL, `'NULL'` generally has the semantics of "not known".  If you don't know the value, then you don't know if a given `id` is larger.  Hence, no rows are returned.

In the second example, instead has an empty set for comparison.  An empty set *is not `NULL`*.  Obviously, any number is greater than all numbers in an empty set.  Hence, all rows are returned.